# How to make multiple loadmore buttons assigned to each individual list on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, list

Hello I have 3 lists on one page that will display and each list has a `load more` button.  I want to be able to click the `loadmore button` and load 3 items per click.

- The problem that I am facing is that when i click the `load more button`, the second page doesnt show up but on the 2nd click it populates only the last page.
- Another is when for instance the button is clicked on `completed` and then clicking the button on `expired` creates duplicates of the expired list.
- So pretty much the all of the buttons are changing all of the lists eventhough they are not corresponding to them.
- I realize that im using url_for which may be the reason im in this problem. perhaps there is a better way to achieve this?
- When clicking `load more` button on the console i get: 
  `www.mywebsite.com/your_essays?page_completed=2".`
  `www.mywebsite.com/your_essays?page_completed=3".`
  `www.mywebsite.com/your_essays?page_expired=2".`

This shows what the current page is based on the url, however if i have multiple lists how can i achieve this to make each list separate from each other? is there a better way to do this??

reservations_controler.rb:

```rails
def your_essays

    user = current_user
  @reservations = user.reservations.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id).where("status = ?", true)

  #pending
  @reservations_pending = user.reservations.where("turned_in = ?", false).where("completed = ?", false).where("due_date >= ?", DateTime.now).order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page_pending]).per_page(3)

   @reservations_pending1 = user.reservations.where("turned_in = ?", false).where("completed = ?", false).where("due_date >= ?", DateTime.now).order(created_at: :desc)

  #completed

  @reservations_completed = user.reservations.where("turned_in = ?", true).where("completed_doc_updated_at <= due_date", true).order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page_completed]).per_page(3)
  @reservations_completed1 = user.reservations.where("turned_in = ?", true).where("completed_doc_updated_at <= due_date", true).order(created_at: :desc)
  #expired
  @reservations_expired = user.reservations.where("due_date <= ?", DateTime.now).where("turned_in = ?", false).where("completed = ?", false).order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page_expired]).per_page(3)
  @reservations_expired1 = user.reservations.where("due_date <= ?", DateTime.now).where("turned_in = ?", false).where("completed = ?", false).order(created_at: :desc)


end
```

my_essays.html.erb:

```html
 <div id="content-load-more-completed">
    <%= render 'your_essays_completed', reservations_completed: @reservations_completed %>
  </div>

  <% unless @reservations_completed.current_page == @reservations_completed.total_pages %>
  <div id="view-more-completed" class="center" style="min-width:100%;" >
   <%= link_to('View More', url_for(page_completed: @reservations_completed.current_page + 1), remote: true, class: 'btn btn-back', style: 'min-width:100%;') %>
   </div>
    <% end %>
        
        
        
  <div id="content-load-more-expired">
   <%= render 'your_essays_expired', reservations_expired: @reservations_expired %>
   </div>

   <% unless @reservations_expired.current_page == @reservations_expired.total_pages %>
   <div id="view-more-expired" class="center" style="min-width:100%;" >
   <%= link_to('View More', url_for(page_expired: @reservations_expired.current_page + 1), remote: true, class: 'btn btn-back', style: 'min-width:100%;') %>
    </div>
   <% end %>
```

my_essays.js.erb:

```js
$('#view-more-completed').click(function (event) {

$('#content-load-more-completed').append("<%=j render 'your_essays_completed', reservations_completed: @reservations_completed, format: 'html' %>");

});

<% if @reservations_completed.current_page == @reservations_completed.total_pages %>
  $('#view-more-completed').remove();
<% else %>
  $('#view-more-completed a').attr('href', '<%= url_for(page_completed: @reservations_completed.current_page + 1) %>');
<% end %>





$('#view-more-expired').click(function (event) {
 
$('#content-load-more-expired').append("<%=j render 'your_essays_expired', reservations_expired: @reservations_expired, format: 'html' %>");
 
});


<% if @reservations_expired.current_page == @reservations_expired.total_pages %>
  $('#view-more-expired').remove();
<% else %>
  $('#view-more-expired a').attr('href', '<%= url_for(page_expired: @reservations_expired.current_page + 1) %>');
<% end %>
```

partials for _your_essays_completed.html.erb and _your_essays_expired.html.erb:

```html
<% reservations_completed.each do |reservation| %>

<!-- content -->

<% end %>


<% reservations_expired.each do |reservation| %>
<!-- content -->

<% end %>
```

Comment: sorry didnt read the entire question, but it looks to me that you just have to also send the div-id to your controller.

Comment: okay if this is the case. then how you do that? ^^